# How to reload list view?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listview, listbox, refresh

I have run into a problem. When the main form load, it call the loadSentnbox()

```
Public Sub loadSentbox()
    logmysql()
    Try

        Dim sqlquery As String
        logmysql()
        sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM files_tr WHERE `from` = '" + user + "'"
        mysqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(sqlquery, mysqlCon)
        'Open the Db
        mysqlCon.Open()
        mysqlReader = mysqlCommand.ExecuteReader
        While mysqlReader.Read
            Dim i As ListViewItem
            ltv_sentbox.BeginUpdate()
            i = ltv_sentbox.Items.Add(mysqlReader.Item("to"))
            i.SubItems.Add(mysqlReader.Item("filename"))
            i.SubItems.Add(mysqlReader.Item("size"))
            i.SubItems.Add(mysqlReader.Item("status"))
            ltv_inbox.Update()
            ltv_inbox.EndUpdate()
        End While
        mysqlCon.Close()
        'ltv_sentbox.Refresh()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
```

It works good !. But I want to update the database from another form and then close the window and update the listview on the original page. I write loadSentbox() in the close event, but listview shows nothing.
What is the solution ? (i'm new to vb.net. Dont write a complex code)

Comment: Make sure you are clearing the ListView items before re-loading (or you will have duplicates when re-reading from the DB), and also make sure you are not calling the loadSentBox() to the instance of the second form. You will probably need to post more code to get some good answers here. You have stated the method you posted works, so the problem is going to be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

Public Sub DatabaseToListview(ByVal strcon As String, ByVal strcmd As String, ByVal list As ListView)

        list.Items.Clear()

        Dim dr1 As SqlClient.SqlDataReader

        Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(strcon)

        Dim i As Integer = 0

        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

        Dim item As New ListViewItem

        con.Open()

            cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strcmd, con)

            dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader

            While (dr1.Read())

                    item = New ListViewItem()

                    item.Text = dr1(0).ToString

                    i = 1

                    While i < dr1.FieldCount

                            item.SubItems.Add(dr1(i).ToString)

                        i = i + 1

                    End While

                list.Items.Add(item)

            End While

            dr1.Close()

            con.Close()

    End Sub